# Reading a file on server using AJAX , whenver data in the file is updated

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, server

I am beginner in programming.
I have a php page and a text file in server. The text file is continuously being updated by a mobile application.I need to read data from this text file  and update he php page based on that data.So php page need to be updated only when the text file is modified. How can I do it using AJAX. Is it possible to do it by using php or java script.

I tried to do it by using php  -  [Continuously updating php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618366/continuously-updating-php-page)

thanx in advance

Comment: Have you write some code?

Comment: If you need to push updates from the server to the client (because your serverside data has changed), you'll need to look into push-mechanisms. You can use websockets for that, for example, or SignalR (for Microsoft stack). Until you decide on a technique, asking a question like this is going to get you very fuzzy answers.

Comment: I haven't written any code. I just want know whether it is possible with AJAX.